# Create a dynamic button via VBA at runtime

Tags: vba, runtime, userform

I created a Userform, that shows a few values from the table (within textboxes) that can be edited and a command button to save those changes back into the table.

Since I use the same template for various values I decided to dynamically create the Userform at runtime. But I can't get the command button to work at all. I cross-checked with various examples (on StackOverflow and other sites, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100490/create-button-dynamically-and-add-onclick-event) and [here](https://www.codeguru.com/vb/controls/vb_activex/activex/article.php/c3499/Create-Controls-Dynamically-VB6.htm)), but I can't find the problem.

This is my (simplified) code. The procedure is being called by a button click event itself (`CommandButton1`). As a workaround, I created a static (empty) UserForm `UserForm1` which I use as a starting point to create a specific configuration of the form dynamically during runtime. Essentially it means that just the form elements are created dynamically. At least for now, but that's fine since I only need one single instance of the form to be displayed at any given time. Eventually, I would like to create the form at runtime too:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  'Set Form
    UserForm1.Caption = "Test"
  'Create Form-Elements (Commandbutton)
    Dim cmdButton01 As MSForms.CommandButton
    Set cmdButton01 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "dynCmdButton01")
    cmdButton01.Width = 50
    cmdButton01.Caption = "Save"
  'Show Form
    UserForm1.Show
  End Sub

Private Sub dynCmdButton01_click()
  MsgBox "Test"
  End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign code to a button created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically)

Comment: @TomBrunberg the missing class module was the problem, not sure if you or TJS was first to answer but feel free to add one if you like.

Comment: I support that you assign @TJS 's answer as the correct one. Cheers

Comment: @TomBrunberg I will, thank you again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a class module and assign the event through it:

- [dynamically create buttons and assign code for the click event (during runtime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically)
- [dynamically assign code to static buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828874/excel-vba-how-to-programmatically-add-code-to-button)

Comment: the missing class module was the problem, not sure if you or Tom was first to answer?!